# Change global webcam settings from terminal

Tags: camera

I need a simple script that can change my webcam settings. I want the changes to be applied globally, just like with guvcview. Most importantly, I want to be able to turn on the auto exposure setting.

I have checked the [man page](https://man.cx/guvcview(1)) and I don't think guvcview allows that from CLI.

Comment: You might use [`v4lctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/v4lctl), which is part of the `xawtv` package.

Comment: @ridgy I've found [this tutorial](http://www.techytalk.info/webcam-settings-control-ubuntu-fedora-linux-operating-system-cli/), you might want to put this comment as an answer for me to accept and upvote (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Jezor comment above and the linked tutorial.

Installing the *v4l-utils* or *v4l2-utils* (depending on your distro) provides the *v4l2-ctl* tool that defaults to using */dev/video0*

Running

```
v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls
```

will list all the settings that can be changed along with their **min**, **max** and **current** values.

you can then set these values with the *--set-ctrl* command
e.g.

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl contrast=40
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl brightness=100
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl saturation=80
```

These were run on a laptop with built in webcam during a Teams video call using Google Chrome and the camera feed was updated instantly.

To use a different video device pass the *--device* option e.g.

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video3 --list-ctrls
```